# How to you add html attribute options in Yii radio button?

Tags: yii

I am trying to use Yii radioButtonList and customize it with an image on top of each radio button.

However, I'm not sure about how to do it and would be grateful if there's any help.

In the documentation:

```
public static string radioButtonList(string $name, string $select, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

for the $htmlOptions=array(), what can you put in there?

I've seen people using 'separator'=> '', can anyone show some examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>100,'class'=>'yourclass')
```

basically it's:

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('validHtmlOption'=>'value','anotherValidHtmlOption'=>'value')
```